# What is this snake?

Tags: species-identification, snake

[image]

What kind of snake is this? It was sighted in Singapore (South-Eastern-Asia) and was ca. 40cm (~ 16 inches) long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be a [Temple Viper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropidolaemus_wagleri) (*Tropidolaemus wagleri*). Hard to tell from the picture, but the head looks spaded like a Temple Viper's and I think they come in the green morph you show